# Compiling Ruby on Mac OS X Snow Leopard

Tags: ruby, path, profile, local

I am trying to follow this tutorial, on the subject of compiling ruby and rubygems on Snow Leopard:
http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-ruby-rubygems-and-rails-on-snow-leopard

I have added this to my `~/.profile`:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
```

But if I write: `echo $PATH` I get:

```
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

But in tutorial it says:

> You should see /usr/local/bin at the
>   beginning of the line returned by the
>   system.

I have installed macports sometime ago and plenty of other software, perhaps it has changed the path.

Anyway, I have tried to proceed with the installation, so I have built ruby, I did:

```
./configure --enable-shared --enable-pthread CFLAGS=-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=1
make
sudo make install
cd ..
```

But when I do `which ruby` I get:

```
/usr/bin/ruby
```

And according to the tutorial that's wrong. Also if I do `ruby -v` I get the older version of ruby that was preinstalled on Snow Leopard and not the one I've compiled.

Thanks.

## UPD:

This is content of my `~/.profile`:

```
export PYTHONPATH="/Users/m/djangocode:$PYTHONPATH"

alias hibernateon="sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 5"
alias hibernateoff="sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 3"

export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
```

I have deleted `~/.bash_profile`, so it has no impact.

Here is the content of `/etc/bashrc`:

```
# System-wide .bashrc file for interactive bash(1) shells.
if [ -z "$PS1" ]; then
   return
fi

PS1='\h:\W \u\$ '
# Make bash check its window size after a process completes
shopt -s checkwinsize
```

and `/etc/profile`:

```
# System-wide .profile for sh(1)

if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
    eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi

if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then
    [ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

I think their contents are Mac OS X defaults. I never touched these.

If I open terminal up and type `echo $PATH` I still get:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

But if I do: `source ~/.profile` then I get what I need:

```
misha-macbookpro:~ m$ . ~/.profile 
misha-macbookpro:~ m$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

And there is no `~/.bashrc` file.

It seems that `~/.profile` doesn't get "sourced" on terminal's start up. What can cause that?

Comment: You should probably make changes to your path in `~/.bashrc`. Also, `/usr/local/bin` should come before `/usr/bin` and `/bin`. You should investigate where it's being set otherwise. Perhaps in `~/.bashrc`, `/etc/profile` or `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set something like this in your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
```

MacPorts is already changing your `$PATH` in that file, so make your modifications there (MacPorts is the `/opt/local` tree)

Comment: thank you, indeed it was the line from ~/.bash_profile (I deleted it, since I don't have MacPorts installed anymore and I don't use it, I use Homebrew).

Answer (score 2):

You should seriously consider [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew)

Answer (score 1):

Apple's Terminal uses the ~/.bash_profile, not a .bashrc nor a .profile.  Yes, its a bit annoying.